# Can I use Laravel's Schema::createDatabase() without first selecting a DB?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8, laravel-schema-builder

I have a little bit of a chicken and egg problem here. I am building a multitenant app in Laravel where each tenant has their own database on a Postgrsql server. So I have a job to create a new tenant that calls:

```
Schema::connection($this->tenant->getDatabaseConnection())->createDatabase($this->tenant->getDatabaseName())
```

So `$this->tenant->getDatabaseConnection()` chooses a tenant DB server to add the tenant to and returns the that's servers connection name. Then `$this->tenant->getDatabaseName()` will return the string of the DB name for that tenant.

I got one small problem. This throws an exception:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: database "port=5432" does not exist (SQL:
> create database "local_tenant_(id)" encoding "utf8")

This is because the connection by default had the DB name as null. And when a user logs into their tenant we dynamically inject getDatabaseName() from the Tenant model into that.

But I can't do that here because the tenant DB does not yet exist. So here are the options I see:

1. choose a random database of an existing tenant on the server to "act as" when creating the new tenant's DB. I don't really like having to hijack another tenant's DB even temporarily like that even though this should have 0 side affects to that tenant. And if it's the first tenant being provisioned on the server, there's no existing DB to use, which makes this a no-go in my book on it's own.
2. I could just use the DB providers API to create the tenant DB. This would be by far the simplest but would break in local and testing environments and therefore I want to avoid.
3. I could just bypass Laravel and establish a direct PDO connection to the database for this, but I would say that's my last resort if I can't find something better.

Technically you don't have to have a DB selected to use the create DB command. That's an idiosyncrasy of Laravel's Schema Builder that it tries to select a DB before calling the method (in this case CreatedDatabase). Is there a way around this, so I can create the DB without Laravel first trying to select a null DB?

Comment: You could do this, I'd like to know why though, and what is your migration strategy down the road, say you have 1000 tenants, how're you going to add a column to a specific table in each database? (I'm asking because I wonder if you've thought this through. and if so, I am interested in your strategy)

Comment: @Tropus A database per tenant strategy is the most scalable multitenancy option. See [this Laracon talk](https://tomschlick.com/laracon-2017-multi-tenancy-talk/) by Tom Schlick on multitenancy strategies. I'm using the [spatie/laravel-multitenancy](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy) package. It handles the core logic to make a tenant "active" for a given request. It dynamically adjusts the 'DB_NAME' in a tenant connection. Any tenant specific models use that connection. But I still have to manually handle provisioning/deprovisioning tenants with this package.

Comment: @Tropus As for migrations, the package includes a way to run any artisan command such as "migrate" as a specific tenant, or you can pass in a list of tenant_id's and it will cycle though all of them. I would run multiple instances of the migrate command each with a distinct list of tenant_id's to migrate. This plus planning ahead on migrations should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is to connect to the `postgres` database in order to run `CREATE DATABASE`. The `postgres` database is always there (unless somebody dropped it), and that is what it is designed for.

Comment: Coming from MySQL I didn't even realize that was just an empty db. I thought that was equivalent to the "mysql" database and didn't want to touch it. Thanks for the tip. Works like a charm. Part of me doesn't like having to select a DB I'm not really using but since its just an empty default it's not a horrible option.